# how to set materilize modal top?

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I'm trying to set `top` of modal
when I set top in `#singlePost` modal is showing even without trigger.
I've tried `$('#singlePost').css("top", "1%");` but it's not  working
also tried this in github
[github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/609)
any solution?

```
<div id="singlePost" class="modal" >
<div class="modal-content">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col m9 s12">
            <img class="input-field" ng-src="img/cover.jpeg" alt="" >
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#singlePost
{
    background-color: #f7f8fa;
    width:90%;
    height:90% !important;
    display: table !important;

}
```

scripts

```
   $('#singlePost').modal('open', {
        dismissible: true,
        inDuration: 200,
        outDuration: 100
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despite this issue [github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/609) `startingTop` not worked for me
I changed `endingTop` and removed    `startingTop`and it's working!